# JSOUP only parse <HEAD> content and ignore rest of HTML (need fast parsing)

Tags: jsoup

is there a way in JSOUP where we can call up a URL but only parse content between the  tags? i.e., I want to avoid loading the entire HTML as its not needed.

I want to reduce the amount of time it takes to parse information from the 3rd party HTML page.

Comment: jsoup can parse only a html fragment but how do you plan to extract html between tags without parsing the whole html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup always fetches the entire page (unless the server closes the connection or some other I/O error occurs), so it won't do this for you.  But you can manually fetch the page (with e.g. `java.net.HttpURLConnection`) and close the connection after reading `</head>` (or `</HEAD>` etc) from the input stream.  If you have an upper bound on the size of the head element, you can use HTTP range requests to fetch only the first N bytes of the page, allowing you to keep the connection open (avoiding another three-way handshake to set up the next connection).  Either way, parse that HTML fragment with [Jsoup.parse(String html ,String baseUri)](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

But unless the pages are extremely large or the server is very close to you, you're unlikely to gain much from this "optimization", because most of the time required to fetch a page is in the round-trip latency to/from the server (time to first byte received), not the time required to receive the rest of the bytes.  Use a profiler to estimate the savings before adding the extra complexity.